# silverlight crash on google chrome and mac osx

Tags: google-chrome, osx-leopard, silverlight

I'm running google chrome (15.0.874.121) on mac os/x 10.5.8 (leopard).

I get the following message on a site using microsoft silverlight to display videos:

```
Silverlight doesn't seem up to date (version 5 expected).
```

I click the link, follow the instructions on the silverlight site, (install, restart browser), notice that chrome on mac "may not be fully compatible" whith silverlight.

I restart, get the same message on the same site, try to load the video, and I get:

```
The following plug-in has crashed: Silverlight Plug-In.
```

Any solution other than "use a different browser"?